# How to compile Clojure codes with native codes via boot.clj in clj-native?

Tags: java, c, clojure, jna

I'm trying to compile the following project:

```
.
├── build.boot
├── resources
│   ├── libhello.so
│   └── test.c
└── src
    └── clj_zig
        ├── core.clj
        ├── libhello.so
        └── test.c
```

This is a test to call c functions from clojure codes.

Here's my build.boot script:

```clj
(set-env!
  :resource-paths #{"src" "resources"}
  :dependencies '[[clj-native "0.9.5"]])

(task-options!
  pom {:project 'clj-zig
       :version "0.0.1"})

(deftask build
  "build my project."
  []
  (comp (aot :all true) (pom) (jar :main 'clj-zig.core)))
```

The clj-native library calls JNA, and try to link them all together.

This is my core.clj

```clj
(ns clj-zig.core
  (:use [clj-native.direct :only [defclib loadlib typeof]]
        [clj-native.structs :only [byref byval]]
        [clj-native.callbacks :only [callback]]
        [clojure.test]))

(defclib test_lib
  (:libname "libhello")
  (:functions
    (mul [int int] int)))

(loadlib test_lib)

(defn- main
  []
  (prn
  (let [a 3
        b 4]
    (mul a b))))
```

the shared object is basically a piece of c file with an extern function "mul".

```c
extern int mul(int x, int y){
  return x * y;
}
```

However, when I tried to build, it throws these messages:

```
Classpath conflict: org.clojure/clojure version 1.8.0 already loaded, NOT loading version 1.6.0
Compiling 1/1 clj-zig.core...
                                       java.lang.Thread.run                        Thread.java:  831
         java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run            ThreadPoolExecutor.java:  630
          java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker            ThreadPoolExecutor.java: 1130
                        java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run                    FutureTask.java:  264
                                                        ...
                        clojure.core/binding-conveyor-fn/fn                           core.clj: 1938
                                          boot.core/boot/fn                           core.clj: 1031
                                        boot.core/run-tasks                           core.clj: 1022
                       boot.task.built-in/eval2561/fn/fn/fn                       built_in.clj:  804
                                          boot.pod/eval-in*                            pod.clj:  471
                                                        ...
   jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke  DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:   43
       jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke      NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:   78
      jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0       NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java
org.projectodd.shimdandy.impl.ClojureRuntimeShimImpl.invoke        ClojureRuntimeShimImpl.java:   97
org.projectodd.shimdandy.impl.ClojureRuntimeShimImpl.invoke        ClojureRuntimeShimImpl.java:  104
                                                        ...
                                          boot.pod/eval-in*                            pod.clj:  468
                                          clojure.core/eval                           core.clj: 3105
                                                        ...
                                          pod$eval21.invoke                      NO_SOURCE_FILE
                                    pod$eval21.invokeStatic                      NO_SOURCE_FILE
                                       clojure.core/compile                           core.clj: 5903
                                    clojure.core/compile/fn                           core.clj: 5903
                                      clojure.core/load-one                           core.clj: 5697
                                                        ...
                                          clojure.core/load                           core.clj: 5876
                                          clojure.core/load                           core.clj: 5892
                                       clojure.core/load/fn                           core.clj: 5893
                                                        ...
                                  clj-native.direct/loadlib                         direct.clj:  147
                                            clj-zig.core/fn                           core.clj:    7
                             com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary                        Native.java:  391
                             com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary                        Native.java:  412
                         com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>                       Library.java:  147
                      com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance                 NativeLibrary.java:  398
                      com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary                 NativeLibrary.java:  271
         java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'libhello': Native library (linux-x86-64/liblibhello.so) not found in resource path ([file:/home/lyh/.boot/cache/tmp/home/lyh/CS/test/clojure/clj-zig/ysn/-thxrk9/, file:/home/lyh/.boot/cache/tmp/home/lyh/CS/test/clojure/clj-zig/ysn/d3mk5k/, file:/home/lyh/.boot/cache/tmp/home/lyh/CS/test/clojure/clj-zig/ysn/-7y4r8e/, file:/home/lyh/.boot/cache/tmp/home/lyh/CS/test/clojure/clj-zig/ysn/r9l3qd/, file:/home/lyh/.boot/cache/tmp/home/lyh/CS/test/clojure/clj-zig/ysn/-e5ddkj/, file:/home/lyh/.boot/cache/tmp/home/lyh/CS/test/clojure/clj-zig/ysn/f5n30/, file:/home/lyh/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.8.0/clojure-1.8.0.jar, file:/home/lyh/.m2/repository/boot/pod/2.8.3/pod-2.8.3.jar, file:/home/lyh/.m2/repository/org/tcrawley/dynapath/1.0.0/dynapath-1.0.0.jar, file:/home/lyh/.m2/repository/org/projectodd/shimdandy/shimdandy-impl/1.2.1/shimdandy-impl-1.2.1.jar, file:/home/lyh/.m2/repository/clj-native/clj-native/0.9.5/clj-native-0.9.5.jar, file:/home/lyh/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna/4.1.0/jna-4.1.0.jar])
clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'libhello': Native library (linux-x86-64/liblibhello.so) not found in resource path ([file:/home/lyh/.boot/cache/tmp/home/lyh/CS/test/clojure/clj-zig/ysn/-thxrk9/, file:/home/lyh/.boot/cache/tmp/home/lyh/CS/test/clojure/clj-zig/ysn/d3mk5k/, file:/home/lyh/.boot/cache/tmp/home/lyh/CS/test/clojure/clj-zig/ysn/-7y4r8e/, file:/home/lyh/.boot/cache/tmp/home/lyh/CS/test/clojure/clj-zig/ysn/r9l3qd/, file:/home/lyh/.boot/cache/tmp/home/lyh/CS/test/clojure/clj-zig/ysn/-e5ddkj/, file:/home/lyh/.boot/cache/tmp/home/lyh/CS/test/clojure/clj-zig/ysn/f5n30/, file:/home/lyh/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.8.0/clojure-1.8.0.jar, file:/home/lyh/.m2/repository/boot/pod/2.8.3/pod-2.8.3.jar, file:/home/lyh/.m2/repository/org/tcrawley/dynapath/1.0.0/dynapath-1.0.0.jar, file:/home/lyh/.m2/repository/org/projectodd/shimdandy/shimdandy-impl/1.2.1/shimdandy-impl-1.2.1.jar, file:/home/lyh/.m2/repository/clj-native/clj-native/0.9.5/clj-native-0.9.5.jar, file:/home/lyh/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna/4.1.0/jna-4.1.0.jar]), compiling:(core.clj:12:1)
             clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'libhello': Native library (linux-x86-64/liblibhello.so) not found in resource path ([file:/home/lyh/.boot/cache/tmp/home/lyh/CS/test/clojure/clj-zig/ysn/-thxrk9/, file:/home/lyh/.boot/cache/tmp/home/lyh/CS/test/clojure/clj-zig/ysn/d3mk5k/, file:/home/lyh/.boot/cache/tmp/home/lyh/CS/test/clojure/clj-zig/ysn/-7y4r8e/, file:/home/lyh/.boot/cache/tmp/home/lyh/CS/test/clojure/clj-zig/ysn/r9l3qd/, file:/home/lyh/.boot/cache/tmp/home/lyh/CS/test/clojure/clj-zig/ysn/-e5ddkj/, file:/home/lyh/.boot/cache/tmp/home/lyh/CS/test/clojure/clj-zig/ysn/f5n30/, file:/home/lyh/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.8.0/clojure-1.8.0.jar, file:/home/lyh/.m2/repository/boot/pod/2.8.3/pod-2.8.3.jar, file:/home/lyh/.m2/repository/org/tcrawley/dynapath/1.0.0/dynapath-1.0.0.jar, file:/home/lyh/.m2/repository/org/projectodd/shimdandy/shimdandy-impl/1.2.1/shimdandy-impl-1.2.1.jar, file:/home/lyh/.m2/repository/clj-native/clj-native/0.9.5/clj-native-0.9.5.jar, file:/home/lyh/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna/4.1.0/jna-4.1.0.jar]), compiling:(core.clj:12:1)
    line: 17
```

I'm not an export in java or clojure, so can anyone tell me how to config the class path in boot.clj, so I can get this compiled?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it up. I can specify the library path via

```clj
(System/setProperty "jna.library.path" "./test/clj_native/test")
```